# Using Shell tools (sed | awk... etc) to compute max, min and average field values from a given sample.dat file

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk

I have a `sample.dat` file which contains experiment values for 10 different
fields, recorded over time. Using `sed`, `awk` or any other shell tool, i need to write a script that reads in sample.data file and for each field computes the max, min and average.

`sample.dat`

```
field1:experiment1: 10.0
field2:experiment1: 12.5
field1:experiment2: 5.0
field2:experiment2: 14.0
field1:experiment3: 18.0
field2:experiment3: 3.5
```

Output

```
field1: MAX = 18.0, MIN = 5.0, AVERAGE = 11.0
field2: MAX = 14.0, MIN = 3.5, AVERAGE = 10.0
```

Comment: start with separating the numbers from each line, and after you can make any calculations with them...

Comment: If you have a lot of data, you'd be better off with Perl. Bash can be quite slow for test manipulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F: '
{
    sum[$1]+=$3;
    if(!($1 in min) || (min[$1]>$3))
        min[$1]=$3;
    if(!($1 in max) || (max[$1]<$3))
        max[$1]=$3;
    count[$1]++
}
END {
  for(element in sum)
      printf("%s: MAX=%.1f, MIN=%.1f, AVARAGE=%.1f\n",
              element,max[element],min[element],sum[element]/count[element])
}' sample.dat
```

Output

```
field1: MAX=18.0, MIN=5.0, AVARAGE=11.0
field2: MAX=14.0, MIN=3.5, AVARAGE=10.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Perl solution I made (substitute the file name for whatever file you use):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(max min sum);

open( my $fh, "<", "sample.dat" ) or die $!;

my %fields;
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    $_ =~ s/\s+//g;
    my @line = split ":";
    push @{ $fields{ $line[0] } }, $line[2];
}

close($fh);

foreach ( keys %fields ) {
    print "$_: MAX="
      . max @{ $fields{$_} };
    print ", MIN="
      . min @{ $fields{$_} };
    print ", AVERAGE="
      . ( (sum @{ $fields{$_} }) / @{ $fields{$_} } ) . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In `bash` with `bc`:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A min
declare -A max
declare -A avg
declare -A avgCnt

while read line; do
  key="${line%%:*}"
  value="${line##*: }"
  if [ -z "${max[$key]}" ]; then
    max[$key]="$value"
    min[$key]="$value"
    avg[$key]="$value"
    avgCnt[$key]=1
  else
    larger=`echo "$value > ${max[$key]}" | bc`
    smaller=`echo "$value < ${min[$key]}" | bc`
    avg[$key]=`echo "$value + ${avg[$key]}" | bc`
    ((avgCnt[$key]++))
    if [ "$larger" -eq "1" ]; then
      max[$key]="$value"
    fi
    if [ "$smaller" -eq "1" ]; then
      min[$key]="$value"
    fi
  fi
done < "$1"

for i in "${!max[@]}"
do
  average=`echo "${avg[$i]} / ${avgCnt[$i]}" | bc`
  echo "$i: MAX = ${max[$i]}, MIN = ${min[$i]}, AVERAGE = $average"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of this python code :

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
[d[(line.split(":")[0])].append(float(line.split(":")[2].strip("\n "))) for line in open("sample.dat")]
for f in d:  print f, ": MAX=", max(d[f]),", MIN=", min(d[f]),", AVG=", sum(d[f])/float(len(d[f]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gnu-R` for something like this:

```
echo "1" > foo
echo "2" >> foo

cat foo \
| r -e \
' 
  f <- file("stdin")
  open(f)
  
  v <- read.csv(f,header=F)
  write(max(v),stdout())
'

2
```

#### For summary statistics,

```
cat foo \
| r -e \
' 
  f <- file("stdin")
  open(f)
  
  v <- read.csv(f,header=F)
  write(summary(v),stdout())
'

# Max, Min, Mean, median, quartiles, deviation, etc.
...
```

#### And in json:

```
... | r -e \
'
  library(rjson)
  f <- file("stdin")
  open(f)
  v <- read.csv(f,header=F)
  json_summary <- toJSON(summary(v))
  write(json_summary,stdout())
'

# same stats 

| jq '.Max'

# for maximum
```

If you are using the linux command line environment, then you probably don't want to reimplement wheels, stay vectorized, and have clean code that is easy to read and develop, and which performs some **standard, composable function**.

In this case, you don't need an object oriented language (using python will tend to induce interface and code bloat and iterations with google, pip, and conda depending on the libs you need and type conversions you have to code by hand), you don't need verbose syntax, and you probably need to deal with dataframes/vectors/rows/columns of numerical data by default.

You probably also want scripts that can float around your particular machine without issues.  If you are on Linux, that probably means: gnu-R.  Install dependencies via `apt-get`.